# tkinter not working on my python 3.7. is their any problem in the way i import it/using it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter()

myLabel = Label(root, text="hello world")

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when i run the code it swnds back

```
'NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined'
```

Comment: if you use `from tkinter import *` then `root = Tk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Tk()` instead of `tkinter()`.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myLabel = Label(root, text="hello world")

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

As importing all`*` from tkinter is discouraged you should import it as `tk`

So your code will look Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

myLabel = tk.Label(root, text="hello world")

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you import

```
 from tkinter import *
```

then should be

```
 root = Tk()
```

If you will import

```
 import tkinter
```

then should be

```
 root = tkinter.Tk()
```

If you will import

```
 import tkinter as tk
```

then should be

```
 root = tk.Tk()
```

---

**BTW:** Last version is very popular because it doesn't use `import *` (which is not prefered) but it lets you use `tk.Tk()`, `tk.Label()`, etc. which is shorter then `tkinter.Tk()`, `tkinter.Label()`, etc. and you can recognize if you use standard `tk.Label()` or themed `ttk.Label()` or own class `Label()`

Comment: schurr, you should accept this answer as this is the original person that answered....